# Kendo-Grid: two field in one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I havetwo fields in my class First Name & Last Name. Currently I am displaying as two column in Kendo-Grid. But now I want it to be display like follow:

```
Name
-------------
Parker, Peter  //i.e. LastName,FirstName
```

I don't know how to do. Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you're using asp.net MVC server-side)
Simply add a new property to your model:

```
public string CombinedNames {
    get { return Lastname + ", " + FirstName; }
}
```

And use that property as a column in Kendo Grid.

Comment: Oh that's so easy. Thanks I was not able to think lyk ur way. Thank u so much.

Comment: It is showing error: semicolon after method or accessor block is not valid

Comment: It works for `get {return Lastname + ", " + FirstName;}`